# Monitor a dom location for a change in Scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I'd like to be able to monitor `dom.window.location.hash` for changes (hopefully in an event-oriented fashion, as opposed to polling). Is there a way to do this with the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure -- you just hook the "hashchange" event, same as in JavaScript. [Here's an example](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/display/PageManager.scala#L80-L84), from my own code.